# _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter app & when i added the app icon it shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Workspace\python demo\Workspace.py", line 553, in <module>
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
File "C:\Users\RAKESH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2109, in wm_iconbitmap    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
```

When first i created the app it's working fine but recently it's not working

```
root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.update()
starttime = time.time()


root.wm_title("Workspace")
ob = Login(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue if the ICO file is in the same directory of the script.  Better check the current working directory (`print(os.getcwd())`) is in the same directory of the script.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by Thyrus works for me fine on Windows, but not on Linux. There I get the same error message as mentioned in the original question. According to https://www.delftstack.com/de/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter I now use the following code which works for me on both systems:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='Capture.png'))
root.mainloop()
```

Therefore I had to convert my '.ico' to '.png' using ImageMagic:

```
convert Capture.ico Capture.png
```

Answer (score 0):

first import tkinter and specify path to icon. This example code will help you understand:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.iconbitmap('/path/to/ico/icon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the `icon.ico` file is stored in the same folder as `.py` file

Comment: did you import tk ?

Comment: yes it's imported

Comment: is icon extension .ico or is it png, jpeg ? Make sure it is ".ico.". If it is, than you can try to remove root.update().

Comment: the icon is `.ico` & also after removing the `root.update()` it didn't work